# NextJS API resolved without sending a response

Tags: javascript, api, rest, next.js

I am learning about getServerSideProps, I have a file 'hello.js' in pages/api/hello.js and the code is:

```
    function Hello({ data }) {
    return (
        <>
            <h1>{data}</h1>
        </>
    )
}
  
// This gets called on every request
export async function getServerSideProps() {
    // Fetch data from external API
    const res = await fetch(`https://ergast.com/api/f1/2021/drivers.json`)
    const data = await res.json()

    // Pass data to the page via props
    return { props: { data } }
}

export default Hello
```

I can't access the page due to the following error: API resolved without sending a response for /api/hello, this may result in stalled requests.

The code has been taken from here with a few tweaks: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props

Comment: You can't use `getServerSideProps` in api route. If you want to create a Page then place it outside of api folder, if you want to create api route then don't use React and `getServerSideProps` there

Comment: Thanks @Danila, I have moved the file out of the API folder and up into the pages folder I can now access the API.